# How to prove the zero vector is a subspace of upper triangle matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have searched StackExchange and have seen a lot of answers that the set of all upper triangular matrices is a subspace of all M<sub>nn</sub> matrices.

What I don't understand is how the zero vector is in this subspace?

If I have a 2x2 M upper triangular matrice and multiply that by 0,

\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}

=

\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}

where the new matrix is no longer an upper triangular matrix. Therefore the zero matrix is NOT in the set of all upper triangular matrices and therefore isn't a subspace of all M<sub>nn</sub> matrices?

Or I am mis-understanding the definition of an upper triangular matrix? Is a matrix considerd upper triangular ONLY if all A<sub>ij</sub> entries = 0 whenever i > j and the matrix has to be a square matrix? Then I suppose I can see how the zero vector will fit into this definition, but my textbook wasn't clear about this.

Any clarification into my thinking would be appreciated, I feel like I am almost there, but just need a little push in the right direction. Also apologies for poor formatting, I searched but was not able to find how to format a matrix equation onto one line...

Comment: First problem:  the zero vector isn't a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ **is** upper triangular.

Comment: @Randall I believe his vector space is the space of upper triangular matrices.

Comment: Oh, I was interpreting "vector" literally, not abstractly.  S/he means the zero matrix.  My fault.

Answer (score 1):

You got the definition of upper triangular wrong. The matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$
is upper triangular if $c=0$. The other elements ($a$, $b$, $d$) don't *have* to be $0$, but **can** be zero.

> Or I am mis-understanding the definition of an upper triangular matrix? Is a matrix considerd upper triangular ONLY if all A<sub>ij</sub> entries = 0 whenever i > j and the matrix has to be a square matrix? Then I suppose I can see how the zero vector will fit into this definition, but my textbook wasn't clear about this.

What is your textbook definition then?

Comment: That was actually my textbook definition. I was getting it mixed up with a diagonal matrix. My apologies

Comment: No problem at all.